# How to get 'class' name like Chrome's dev console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

Below is a piece of code evaluated in Chrome's console. A function constructor is created anonymously and used to construct an object. Chrome happily prints the real constructor's name 'Foo'. But, I can't find a way to get it using standard JS. Where's the magic?

```
> var exports = {}
undefined
> (function(){var Foo = function() {}; Foo.prototype = "";  exports.bar = Foo;})()
undefined
> obj = new exports.bar();
Foo {}
> obj.constructor.name
'Object'
> obj.__proto__
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
> obj.__proto__.name
undefined
> obj
Foo {}
```

Comment: this is Transpiled from ES6 to ES5

Answer (score 0):

To get `Foo` you can `exports.bar.name`

```
if (obj.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(exports.bar)) {
  console.log(exports.bar.name);
}
```

Comment: obj.__proto__.constructor.name returns 'Object'. I want to get 'Foo'

Comment: `exports.bar.name`